# What architecture to use in my pc

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm new to Ubuntu, I have a dell Inspiron n4010 with Intel core i5 540m 2.5 ghz (1st generation), 5gb RAM.
This machine have from factory Windows 7 Professional x64.
My question is, which is the better Ubuntu for my PC? x64 or x32. I have read a lot of forum posts but I can't decide which is the better one for my PC.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit - I genrally use 32bit PAE versions for Dual-Core Intel i5 2nd Gen + 6GB ram laptop, whilst 64bit for AMD Processor desktop. The main difference is the amount of RAM (or memory) that you can have - 32bit can only do up to 4GB, whilst 64bit or 32bit PAE can have more than 4GB ram. 32bit is sometimes better for compatibility, but 64bit is catching up, especially with flash-player.

Comment: if your window7 64biut is working with lag then go for 64 bit ubuntu ,, else mention the complete configuration..

Comment: Canonical now recommends the 64-bit version (starting with 12.04, I believe), so I'd go with that unless you have a specific reason not to.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can think of that you would use the 32 bit version of Ubuntu in a PC with a multi-core, 64-bit processor is if you had less than 4 GB of RAM. Even then, you will still see better CPU performance with the 64 bit version, just less efficient RAM usage.

Since you have a machine that is specifically designed to run a 64-bit operating system, you should go with that. Nowadays, most applications run on 64 bit machines. Unless you have a specific application you want to compile and run for 32 bit Linux, you should go for the 64 bit version.

Comment: Thanks for every body, i made all procedures and my pc is for 64bit, so i'll continue on it thanks